# How to display images saved in web folder on page in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

```
$img = Url::to('@web/uploads/');                 
$image = '<img src="'.$img.'" width="600" />';  
?>  

<img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/backend/web/uploads/'.$model->id_image ?>" class=" img-responsive" >  
<?php echo Html::img('@web/img/icon.png', ['class' => 'pull-left img-responsive']); ?>
```

I want to display images from my web directory to page, how to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try:

```
echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/img/icon.png', ['class' => 'pull-left img-responsive']);
```

To get all the files use:

```
print_r(\yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles(realpath($config['sourcePath']).'\img',['only'=>['*.jpg']]));
```

**Updated:**

use `Yii::getAlias('@webroot')` instead of `realpath($config['sourcePath']).'\img'`

For displaying all the images:

```
$imgFiles = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getAlias('@webroot'),['only'=>['*.jpg']]);

 foreach($imgFiles as $files)
{
        $explodeImg = explode('\\', $files);
        $imgName = end($explodeImg);
        echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/img/'.$imgName, ['class' => 'pull-left img-responsive']);
}
```

Comment: how to get all images in that folder?

Comment: use filehelper findfiles() method for that

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: use @webroot then .. Please check the updated answer. Also append the directory/folder name to webroot if needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85415/discussion-between-chinmay-and-saurabh).